# Where to put the carthage file when using the AWS-sdk-iOS

Tags: xcode, amazon-web-services, carthage

The cartFile creates a MyProject.xworkspace.

It seems that this file is not in the same folder as the MyProject.xcodeproj.
Is it a problem ?

Secondly, when I istall the AWS librairies with Carthage, I have to add :

Under the Build Phases tab in your Target, click the + button on the top left and then select New Run Script Phase. Then setup the build phase as follows. Make sure this phase is below the Embed Frameworks phase.

```
 Shell /bin/sh

 bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/AWSCore.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"
```

When I add "import AWSCore" in a source file, I get "No such modue AWSCore". Could it be that the path is wrong ?
Is it possible to get the value of BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR ?, of FRAMEWORKS_FOLDE_PATH ?